# How to match three columns differing in the pattern?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-management

I have similar data to the following (but larger one):

```
example <- rbind(data.frame(species = "A", trait1 = "yes", trait2 = NA),      
     data.frame(species = "A", trait1 = NA, trait2 = "yes"), 
     data.frame(species = "B", trait1 = NA, trait2 = "no"), 
     data.frame(species = "B", trait1 = "yes", trait2 = NA), 
     data.frame(species = "B", trait1 = "no", trait2 = NA),
     data.frame(species = "B", trait1 = "no", trait2 = NA), 
     data.frame(species = "C", trait1 = NA, trait2 = "no"), 
     data.frame(species = "C", trait1 = "no", trait2 = NA), 
     data.frame(species = "D", trait1 = "yes", trait2 = NA), 
     data.frame(species = "D", trait1 = NA, trait2 = "yes"), 
     data.frame(species = "E", trait1 = NA, trait2 = "no"), 
     data.frame(species = "E", trait1 = "no", trait2 = NA), 
     data.frame(species = "E", trait1 = "no", trait2 = NA))
```

Here, trait2 is a fixed value (1 value for 1 species), but trait1 is variable within species. For each trait value, data for species come from different rows. After data management, I want to keep the variability existed in trait1, and this seems to make the process a bit complex.

Finally, I want to transform this data frame in R to the following one:

```
ex.res <- rbind(data.frame(species = "A", trait1 = "yes", trait2 = "yes"), 
        data.frame(species = "B", trait1 = "yes", trait2 = "no"),
        data.frame(species = "B", trait1 = "no", trait2 = "no"),
        data.frame(species = "B", trait1 = "no", trait2 = "no"),
        data.frame(species = "C", trait1 = "no", trait2 = "no"),
        data.frame(species = "D", trait1 = "yes", trait2 = "yes"),
        data.frame(species = "E", trait1 = "no", trait2 = "no"),
        data.frame(species = "E", trait1 = "no", trait2 = "no"))
```

I have tried many things, including some basic data management tools in R, and also `duplicated`, `unique`, and `match_df` functions, but they were not successful in doing this completely.

Maybe a combined version of such functions could have been worked, but I am not able to do this. Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr);example %>% group_by(species) %>% summarise_all(~ list(na.omit(.))) %>% unnest`

Comment: I got an error message: "All nested columns must have the same number of elements."

Comment: Is it based on the example showed.  Not getting that for me

Comment: Or if the lengths are different in original data, keep it as a `list` column

Comment: yes, my response was based on the example data I provided here

Comment: Sorry, couldn't reproduce it with `dplyr_0.8.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach by using base R,

```
first_part <- example[!is.na(example$trait1),]
second_part <- example[!is.na(example$trait2),]

merge(first_part[,-3], second_part[,-2], by="species")



   species trait1 trait2
1       A    yes    yes
2       B    yes     no
3       B     no     no
4       B     no     no
5       C     no     no
6       D    yes    yes
7       E     no     no
8       E     no     no
```

Comment: In reality, I have three traits to organize but the `merge` function seems can not do it this work properly. Any other suggestion? @maydin

Comment: I am not so sure since I didn't see the real data but, you may add another part like `third_part <- example[!is.na(example$trait3),]`. And you may merge the last one with the already merged data. But in this setting, you need not to forget that, while you are merging, you need to cancel out the other traits. So, since there will be three trait column and one species column than you should assign `my_first_merge <- merge(first_part[,-c(3,4)], second_part[,-c(2,4)], by="species")` . And than, `merge(my_first_merge, third_part[,-c(2,3)], by="species")`

Comment: thank you @maydin, I successfully adapted the code to my data.

Comment: Good to hear that!